# Refund functionality in Paypal Adaptive Payments

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Following paypal [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-delayedChainedPayment-curl-etc/)
i have setup Delayed Chained Payment Using Adaptive Payments but i cannot see any reference for how to get refunds. Can anyone please help in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

The information you are looking for can likely be found in [this document](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Refund_API_Operation/?mark=adaptive%20payment%20refund)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I shall check and let you know if it solves my problem.